# Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage bug

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tabbedpage

I have created an application with Xamarin.Forms for android and ios. On android everything works fine, but i have a little problem with ios. My app contains a TabbedPage that is composed of two different tabs. Each tab is a content page and it has a listview inside it. This is the code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views">

<TabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage x:Name="page1">
        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <ToolbarItem Icon="more.png" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding JobsToDo}"
                  x:Name="listView"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                  RowHeight="240"
                  SeparatorColor="Transparent"
                  BackgroundColor="#fffffd"
                      SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource startJob}" />
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage x:Name="page2">
        <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding JobsEnded}"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                  RowHeight="240"
                  SeparatorColor="#4b4b4b"
                  BackgroundColor="#fffffd"
                      SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource endJob}" />
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

The problem is that second ListView in "page2" is frozen and I can't scroll it. ListView in "page1" works correctly. I've noticed, that when you use TabbedPage on IOS with 2 or more tabs and one of the tab contains ListView, then ListView is also frozen. Is it a bug or I've done something incorrectly? Please help me

Comment: Which version of XF are you using?  Have you tried it on more than one device or emulator?  Does the 2nd ListView have enough data to cause it to scroll?  Does it respond to tap or select events?

Comment: Hi, I can not reproduce this in my local site. If you could share the sample project link in question when you have time, it will be better to check where problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem. I've updated XF from 4.7 to the latest and everything works correct now on both platforms.